# Whats the best way to use regex for segregating data

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a program which will filter out cross environment access, ex. prod should not have access on Dev/QA objects and vise-versa.

So far I am using a IN condition to check and filter out this data,How can i achieve this using Regular expressions or other effective ways  ? please suggest

sample code :

```
lst_role_objects = []
for row in exct_role_obj:
if (('_PROD' in row[0] or  'PROD_'  in row[0] or '_PROD_'  in row[0]) and  ('PREPROD' not in row[0])):

    if ('_DEV' in (row[1].split('.')[0]) or  'DEV_'  in (row[1].split('.')[0]) or '_DEV_'  in (row[1].split('.')[0]) or '_QA' in (row[1].split('.')[0]) or  'QA_'  in (row[1].split('.')[0]) or '_QA_'  in (row[1].split('.')[0])         or '_PREPROD' in (row[1].split('.')[0]) or  'PREPROD_'  in (row[1].split('.')[0]) or '_PREPROD_'  in (row[1].split('.')[0])):


        print(row[0])
        print(row[1].split('.')[0])
        lst_role_objects.append((row[0],row[1]))


for row in exct_role_obj:
if ('_PREPROD' in row[0] or  'PREPROD_'  in row[0] or '_PREPROD_'  in row[0]) or 'QA'  in row[0]:

    if (( 'PREPROD' not in (row[1].split('.')[0]) ) and ( 'QA' not  in (row[1].split('.')[0]))):
        print(row[0])
        print(row[1].split('.')[0])
        lst_role_objects.append((row[0],row[1]))

for row in exct_role_obj:
if ('_DEV' in row[0] or  'DEV_'  in row[0] or '_DEV_'  in row[0] or              'DEV'  in row[0]) :

    if ( 'DEV' not in (row[1].split('.')[0]) ):
        print(row[0])
        print(row[1].split('.')[0])
        lst_role_objects.append((row[0],row[1]))




Sample data :
ROLE , OBJECTS
PROD_A_TEST , DA_DEV.PROD.SLS
PROD_A_TEST , DA_PROD.PROD.SLS
PROD_A_TEST , DA_PREPROD.PREPROD.SLS
PREPROD_A_TEST , DA_PREPROD.PREPROD.SLS
TEST_PREPROD_A , DA_PREPROD.PREPROD.SLS
TEST_PREPROD_A , DA_PROD.PREPROD.SLS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for all the cases you've mentioned here. Not properly tested.

```
lst_role_objects = []
for row in exct_role_obj:
    if re.match("^([A-Z_]*_)?PROD(_[A-Z_]*)?$", row[0]) and re.match("^([A-Z_]*_)?(DEV|QA|PREPROD)(_[A-Z_]*)?\..*", row[1]):
        print row[0], row[1].split('.')[0]
        lst_role_objects.append((row[0], row[1]))

for row in exct_role_obj:
    if re.match("^([A-Z_]*_)?(PREPROD|QA)(_[A-Z_]*)?$", row[0]) and re.match("^((?!([A-Z_]*)(PREPROD|QA))([A-Z_]*)\..*)$", row[1]):
        print row[0], row[1].split('.')[0]
        lst_role_objects.append((row[0], row[1]))

for row in exct_role_obj:
    if re.match("^([A-Z_]*_)?DEV(_[A-Z_]*)?$", row[0]) and re.match("^(?!.*(DEV)).*$", row[1]):
        print row[0], row[1].split('.')[0]
        lst_role_objects.append((row[0], row[1]))
```

Try it out yourself to include the missing testcases.